# Fetch response times in JMeter running remotely

Tags: time, jmeter, response, performance-testing

Ok so I set up my JMeter to run remotely using one slave computer (possibly more to come), and it's working out for the most part EXCEPT that I can't fetch the response time over time-graphs function using the JMeter plugin. I'm still able to use the "PerfMon Metrics" tool to get the CPU/Memory values from the slave computer, so I don't understand how I'm not able to get the response time results.

Does anyone have any experience using that function?

Answer (score 0):

I would check the master- slave configuration: be sure that

- the same Jmeter release is used
- same directory tree structure is used
- Jmeter-plugins are installed on both systems
- ...

If you use a standard "Summary report" listener, and save data to a file in the master, then you can reload and analyse the data off line with any listener.

HTH